# MySQL - next / previous ID wih cycling

Tags: mysql, database, max, min

I need to create previous / next functionality with cycling. My current solution, If I select `MAX(ID)` gives next as `NULL`.

How can I most efficiently get  `MIN(ID)`  instead of `NULL`(and vice versa for other direction). Of course, I can use `IF` or just create second query if my result is `NULL`, but I wonder if there is better solution.

My table has three columns

ex:

```
ID     foto    like

3        A      0
4        B      0
5        C      0
10       D      0
```

If I select ID 4 next is 5, prev is 3 //this solution I have

For ID 3, next is 4, **previous is 10** //thats what I want

For previous / next I use this query

```
(
    SELECT MIN(`ID`) AS id 
    FROM fotos 
    WHERE `ID` > '$this->id'
    ORDER BY `like` DESC
)
UNION
(
    SELECT MAX(`ID`) AS id 
    FROM fotos 
    WHERE `ID` < '$this->id'                                            
    ORDER BY `like` DESC
)
```

`$this->id` is actually selected and displayed foto

Comment: you want next and previous id of current `foto` am i right ??

Comment: @dianuj Yes.. exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for next and previous id for the current `foto` you can do like this

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT id FROM `foto` WHERE id<'$this->id' ORDER BY DESC id LIMIT 1),
       (SELECT  MAX(id) FROM `foto`))  AS `prev`,
       COALESCE((SELECT id FROM `foto` WHERE id>'$this->id' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 ),
       (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `foto`)) AS `next`
```

Hope it works fine for your needs

Comment: Solution is nearly OK, I accepted It. Only problem is, that seocnd part of COALESCE with MIN/MAX is not respecting ORDER BY as the first part. But I have it incorrect in my solution as well.