# Next and previous MYSQL based on random order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a database with many records on it. The records do have an unique index.
I'm using the following MYSQL query in order to create a randomly ordered list of the records:

```
SELECT  `image_id` ,  `image_name` ,  `image_type` ,  `image_height` ,  `image_width` ,  `image_title` FROM  `images` WHERE  `active` =  '1' ORDER BY RAND($rand_order)
```

$rand_order is then saved on a session so the same order can be recreated later.
After a user clicks on a image (I will have the image_id) I want to get the image_id of the next and previous rows.

I have tried to use the following query but didn't work:

```
SELECT  `image_id` FROM `images` WHERE  `active` =  '1' AND `image_id` > '$cureent_image_id' ORDER BY RAND($rand_order)
```

I also have tried to get the row number of the current record and use the limit to show the other images but not sure how to get that info the first time users clicks on a link without adding it to the URL.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to get the id for the next and previous?

Comment: next and previous with random dont mix.Next compared to what?Even if you have an auto increment is useless in this case.Maybe put the random order data in a table and add an order column to be used for previous and next.

Comment: [**MySQL - next / previous ID wih cycling**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086267/mysql-next-previous-id-wih-cycling/17086521#17086521)

Comment: You can randomly select "next" and "previous" values and then remember it

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question. It seems you want to generate a random permutation of the rows in your table, then save it so your user can navigate forward and backward in that permutation. Is that correct?  Or, are you choosing a random starting image, and then allowing your user to navigate forward and backward in the images' natural order (image_id order)?

Comment: @Mihai, I just stated the fact that I have auto increment in case that it might help. That seems like a good idea but requires storing the randomly ordered sequence which is kinda wasteful

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, That doesn't solve the problem because I'll end up with the same problem as my first solution

Comment: @OllieJones, I'm trying to generate a randomly ordered list of images and give users the ability to got backwards and forwards on that list.

Comment: Hang on. What's `RAND($rand_order)` supposed to do?

Comment: @Strawberry, it just returns the rows in a random order which can be reconstructed later on. In other words, I can get the same random order later on

Comment: Ah, I see. OK, carry on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is select the rand($rand_order) as one of the selected fields and then
Save your Image_id that user has clicked on. and then in this example the image_id that user has clicked on is 6. And then use the same rand($rand_order) to grab the previous and next using the 2 bottom queries.

See this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc54e/17/3)

```
SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
FROM  `images` 
WHERE  `active` =  '1' ORDER BY rowOrder;

SET @image_id=6; /* your user clicked on this image_id */

SELECT T1.* FROM
(SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
 FROM  `images` 
 WHERE  `active` =  '1'
)T1
 WHERE T1.rowOrder < (SELECT rowOrder FROM
                           (SELECT  `image_id`,
                            RAND(11) as rowOrder
                            FROM  `images` 
                            WHERE  `active` =  '1'
                            )T2
                       WHERE image_id=@image_id
                       )
ORDER BY rowOrder DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT T1.* FROM
(SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
 FROM  `images` 
 WHERE  `active` =  '1'
)T1
WHERE T1.rowOrder > (SELECT rowOrder FROM
                           (SELECT  `image_id`,
                                     RAND(11) as rowOrder
                             FROM  `images` 
                             WHERE  `active` =  '1'
                            )T2
                      WHERE image_id=@image_id
                      ) 
ORDER BY rowOrder ASC LIMIT 1;
```

better yet, if you save the `image_id` and the `rowOrder` of the image that the user has clicked on to get your previous and next you can see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc54e/21/3)

```
SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
FROM  `images` 
WHERE  `active` =  '1' ORDER BY rowOrder;

SET @rowOrder=0.424008598946; /* or if you choose to save rowOrder from previous query
                                 of the image that user has clicked on and save the image_id
                              */
SET @image_id=6;

SELECT T1.* FROM
(SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
 FROM  `images` 
 WHERE  `active` =  '1'
)T1
 WHERE T1.rowOrder < @rowOrder
   AND T1.image_id != @image_id
ORDER BY rowOrder DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT T1.* FROM
(SELECT  `image_id` ,`image_name`,`image_type`,  
        `image_height`,`image_width`,`image_title`,
        RAND(11) as rowOrder
 FROM  `images` 
 WHERE  `active` =  '1'
)T1
WHERE T1.rowOrder > @rowOrder
  AND T1.image_id != @image_id
ORDER BY rowOrder ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I am doing the `T1.image != @image_id` above because the `rowOrder` that is saved is not an exact value it's rounded off, so when we compare to the `T1.rowOrder > @rowOrder` we might get that row back so to make sure we don't get the row back we just make sure it's not equal to the saved `@image_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the first query doesn't return any rows!
I tried it in PHPMyAdmin and it only said your query was executed

Comment: I don't understand why you're not getting any rows, you should if you have active images. It's just select a random number as rowOrder, nothing fancy there.

Comment: Thanks for the query it worked perfectly when using with Mysql_query in php. Although for some reason it fails in PHPMyAdmin

Answer (score 4):

What you can do, is get, with your results, save the position of the element:

```
SELECT  `image_id` ,  ...  FROM  `images` 
    WHERE `active` =  '1' ORDER BY RAND($rand_order)
```

And when processing the results, you save the position the ID in the order

And then, to get the next, you set the offset of the query, which will give you the element in that position

```
SELECT  `image_id` ,  ..., FROM  `images` 
    WHERE `active` =  '1' ORDER BY RAND($rand_order) offset X limit 1
```

You can check in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5355f/12

Comment: Never knew that RAND() takes an argument.

Comment: "If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: Deterministic rand() is the best kind of rand() :)

Comment: I didn't now that RAND() takes a seed value either good to know!

Comment: @MikeB over 17K of reputation points and you didn't know know? Mike? tsk tsk kidding.

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure if I understood the solution correctly. So I have to do a while loop and find the position of the current id and then use the offset to go to the next or previous record? If so is there a way to eliminate the while loop because it sounds wasteful

Comment: If I add values after generating that random seed what happens to the values newly inserted,in terms of the existing random order?

Comment: @Mihai in my experience if you change the query or the database in anyway it is going to result in a different order

Comment: You only need to keep track of the positions when you are generating a listing. If you only start by showing the first image, you already know it's at position 0, so you don't need to search for that. Then, the next image will be the one at offset 1, and so on.

Comment: Yes, if you change the query or the database the order will probably be affected. Same thing if you add elements to the middle of the table instead of to the end.